# Is @NSApplicationMain documentation for swift correct?

Tags: swift, cocoa

Swift [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html) for `@NSApplicationMain` reads:

> Using this attribute is equivalent to calling the
>   NSApplicationMain(*:*:) function and passing this class’s name as the
>   name of the delegate class.

But `NSApplicationMain` signature receives only `argc` and `argv`, no way to pass "class name" to it. Across the internet I have found two "examples" how `@NSApplicationMain` equivalent can be used. First one simply calls `NSApplicationMain`:

```
NSApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv)
```

Second one creates shared application singleton and sets delegate to it:

```
NSApplication.sharedApplication()
NSApp.delegate = AppDelegate()
NSApplicationMain(Process.argc, Process.unsafeArgv)
```

Surprisingly, wizard-created app works with both versions (ex delegate is used and I can `NSLog` from it)! How can this be? Maybe delegate is ignored for osx apps and one specified in `main nib file` is always used? Or it's some hidden logic while `NSApplicationMain` and `UIApplicationMain` that I can't yet grasp? Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the documentation appears to be not quite correct there. I'd recommend [filing a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) so they know to fix the docs.

The traditional way to set up a Cocoa app goes something like this:

1. Info.plist specifies the principal class of the app bundle (`NSApplication` or a subclass thereof)
2. `MainMenu.nib` (or `xib`) file contains an instance of the app delegate class
3. Call `NSApplicationMain` from C `main`, and it uses the info from steps 1 and 2 to set up your app.

You can also do it all programmatically in C `main` as you've shown in your question.

The Swift `@NSApplicationMain` directive automatically handles launching the app, and sets the delegate to the class you apply that directive to (so you no longer need a nib to set the delegate, nor do you need to set the delegate programmatically).